# How would i can get customized ObjectMapper?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I use this bean for mapping customizing:

```
@Bean
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer(CustomAnnotationIntrospector customAnnotationIntrospector) {
    return builder -> builder.serializationInclusion(NON_NULL)
        .annotationIntrospector(customAnnotationIntrospector);
}
```

I suppose, that used only in the Spring's filters, but i would want to get ObjectMapper object customizing with it in the code:

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

How i can get it?

Comment: You already get the modified one, so not sure what this question is about.

Comment: @M.Deinum ObjectMapper is not component. Would it autowired in?

Comment: Spring Boot does expose an `ObjectMapper` through the `JacksonAutoConfiguration`. See [the sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jackson/JacksonAutoConfiguration.java#L102)